# What is the cleanest way I can pick up all of my dog's poop on grass?

Tags: dogs, cleaning, defecation, ethics

This is somewhat of both a [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/) and a Pets question. My question is also short - but I think it's pretty self-explanatory.

---

When my dog poops on grass (such as on my lawn or a park) I find it difficult to pick up. I use [standard poop bags](https://earthrated.com/en/product/leash-dispenser-with-15-bags-unscented/). While I get a majority of the feces into the bag, there are still some clumps stuck in the grass. I also would like to avoid pulling up grass. It becomes increasingly harder to pick them up while keeping the feces that I have picked up in the bag. Overall, it becomes a disaster fast.

What is the cleanest way I can pick up *all* of my dog's poop on grass (if there is one)? Or is just getting the majority of it okay (it might be fine for my backyard. but I wouldn't want someone at a park to step in the remains of my dog's poop)?

Comment: Not an answer, but your dog certainly isn't the only creature pooping in the park. :) Personally I'm of the opinion that getting most is good enough, nature gets the rest, but I'll see what people who've had dogs in the last decade or two say!

Comment: As "owner" of a wild running child I am very happy, that dog owners try to pick up as much as they can :D Thank you for this question!

Answer (score 1):

For your own yard, get a dog poo rake and keep it handy. They are modeled after horse poo pitchforks, but downsized. They come with a little "tray with handle" that you can rake the poo into, and then dump into garbage.

We have 5 dogs (rescues) and keeping the yard clean would be impossible without a poo rake.

Here's a search that returns dozens of them on Amazon, around $25. You can also get them at pet stores and farm stores.

https://www.amazon.com/s?k=dog+poo+rakes

Answer (score 0):

I've found that letting the poop dry a bit (a few hours at least) will really help get you pick it up. The poop will adhere to itself vs the grass and when you go to pick it up, you will be able to get all of it. But in order to use this method you must be ok with leaving it in the grass for a bit (in your lawn only). If you don't want to do this, then pick up the poop as you would normally do and spray the area with a hose.

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! This answers the question in part but not full. Do you also have an advice for the "dog walking in the park" version?